# Passing object in Navigation MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I'm developing small app to pratice and I'm having a problem understanding why the object I pass is Null.

I have a main ViewModelPage where I have a Button:

```
        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task CellDoubleTapped()
        {
            Patient patient = new Patient(Id, Date);
            var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "obj", patient }
            };
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(EditingPage)}", navigationParameter);
        }
```

With this button I wanted to open a new page "EditingPage", where I pass my patient object, and there I present the user with fields to edit.

My EditingViewModel:

```
    [QueryProperty(nameof(obj), "obj")]
    public partial class EditingViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        public Patient obj { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }

        public EditingViewModel()
        {
            ShowFields();
        }

        private void ShowFields()
        {
            Date = obj.Date;
        }
    }
```

I recieve an Exception stating my obj is NULL. "object reference not set to an instance of an object"
Can you help me understand which concepts I'm not understanding.

I expected to access the object I created in a page in another page. I'm trying to pass it through Navigation like presented in the documentation from Microsoft. Maybe my error is not about that but there's a concept about passing classes I'm consfusing

Comment: You are trying to get the value in the constructor before the properties have been set.  The constructor is the very first thing that is executed when an object is created

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to solve the issues I had.

Comment: How did you resolve the issue?